# Netty Best Practices

Tags: netty

Is anyone aware of any documentation on the meaning and/or effect of the various setting of Nettys [ChannelOptions](http://netty.io/5.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelOption.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Those are socket options and descriptions can be found in your operating system's setsockopt documentation (SET SOCKet OPTions). Here is the documentation for [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx) and [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setsockopt).

Answer (score 1):

These channel options map directly to properties on [ChannelConfig](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelConfig.html) and its subclasses like [SocketChannelConfig](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/socket/SocketChannelConfig.html) or [DatagramChannelConfig](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/socket/DatagramChannelConfig.html). The javadoc for those types goes into more detail on the various options. Many of these correspond to OS socket options as Alex said.